# HDFS 2.8+: are local data nodes preferred for reading by clients?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was wondering if there is the read-side equivalent to the configuration option `dfs.namenode.block-placement-policy.default.prefer-local-node`, or do HDFS clients try to read from data nodes that share the same host name/ip address?

Example: is it a good idea to deploy a SolrCloud cluster along with HDFS data nodes? Will the solr daemons prefer the local data node daemons for reading?

Comment: Data nodes prefer NODE LOCAL operations, then RACK LOCAL. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: no,updating my question

Comment: Solr isn't on HDFS by default. But assuming that's how you've configured it, HDFS still prefers local data nodes. However, just like a Spark standalone cluster, any remote or inter cluster network operations should be negligible with multi gigabit networking

Comment: that's cool. and I can probably use a balancer to make sure the solr cluster nodes each have a full replica of the shards.

Comment: Cloudera has a Solr on HDFS tuning page https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/search_tuning_solr.html